# Bootstrap save current tab with gridview pagination in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I was trying to add Pagination to my GridView. The gridview is inside a tab that is one of some tabs.

The HTML Code is:

```
<div id="Tabs" class="row">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I used the trick of saving the current tab id and everytime the page is loaded to show this tab:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="TabName" runat="server" />
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var tabName = $("[id*=TabName]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=TabName]").val() : "home";
            $('#Tabs a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
            $("#Tabs a").click(function () {
                $("[id*=TabName]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
            });
        });
```

The Page_load code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            populateAllGrids();
        }
        else
            TabName.Value = Request.Form[TabName.UniqueID];

    }
```

It works great when I click a button inside a tab, but when I click the link of the pagination, it sets the TabName value as the link itself.

For example, it will set this:

```
ctl00$ContentSection$TabName:javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentSection$grvManufacturers','Page$2')
```

By the way, when I run the link that will move me to the second page of the GridView from Chrome's Console, it works fine.

Any idea what is making it acts like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what was the problem.

The problem exists in the script code. It listens to all `<a>` links in the tabs, and sets TabName's value to their href. It works great when the only links in the tabs, are the tab buttons theirself. But the pagination buttons are also `<a>` links and then it doesn't work.

Here's the fixed script that will work any time:

```
<script>
        $('#ContentSection_ddlOptions').selectpicker();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tabName = $("[id*=TabName]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=TabName]").val() : "addManufacturer";
            $('#Tabs > .nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
            $("#Tabs > .nav-tabs a").click(function () {
                $("[id*=TabName]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: so help full. i faced the same problem and tried this... it worked.. nice